# Get python full bit length

Tags: python-3.x, string, networking, hex

If I have the following hex value:

```
>>> 0x0000000000e04000400100000a0000040a000000
```

It has a length of 40 hex digits (need to include the initial 0-padding). Is there an easy way to "keep the" leading padding and easily get the length? For example, I would like this to return 160:

```
>>> 0xe04000400100000a0000040a000000.bit_length()
120
```

Answer (score 1):

For numerical values, programming languages do not store information about the number of leading zeros before the first significant figure. Try storing it as a string instead.

Comment: Would `string` be better than using a `bytes` or `bytesarray` type?

Comment: A bytearray is a great idea.